# Does Python create a new list when a sliced list is a parameter in a recursive function?

Tags: python, recursion, big-o

For the purposes of understanding recursion and its performance in Python I wrote a recursive function that returns the maximum in the list:

```
def max_list(A):
    print(id(A)) # debugging purposes
    if len(A) > 1:
        max_list_tail = max_list(A[:-1])
    else:
        max_list_tail = A[0]
    if A[-1] > max_list_tail:
        return A[-1]
    else:
        return max_list_tail
```

The idea behind this function is that if the last element of the current list is greater than the maximum among the 'tail' of the list, which is, all the elements, except for the last one, that the last one is the maximum, otherwise the maximum of the tail is the maximum.

As you can see, I pass a sliced list `A[:-1]` as a parameter.

**Questions**:

1. Am I right saying the following: Each time I pass `A[:-1]` a new list is created, which is a copy of my old list except for the last element? For debugging purposes I print the id of each sliced list and the ids are different which prompts me to think I'm right but I want confirmation from the expert community.
2. If 1. is yes, that's true, what is the time complexity of my function? Can I say that it is `O(n^2)` because it takes `O(n)` to find the maximum in the initial list and `O(n)` to create a copy of the current list each time I recursively call the function?

Comment: Yes it creates a new list. Yes your function takes about `O(n^2)` time.